# React: How to refactor this to prevent a whole re-render and encapsulate it towards the component that matters?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, repaint, use-effect, rerender

I am using a parent component that defines a `useState` to manage messages that I want to show in a panel

Something like this (pseudo-code)

```js
const Com1 = ({message, setMessage}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fun = async () => {
      if (message) {
        await wait(4000)
        setMessage('')
      }
    }

    const stillMounted = { value: true }
    fun(stillMounted)
    return () => (stillMounted.value = false)
  }, [message])

  return <Message>{message}</Message>
}

const Com2 = ({setMessage}) => {
  if (condition) setMessage('important message`)
  return <></>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  return (
  <>
    <Com1 message={message} setMessage={setMessage} />
    <Others1 />
    <Others2 />
    <Com2 setMessage={setMessage} />
  </>
  )
}
```

The problem is that I would like that only the `<Com1> -> <Message>` component gets repainted, but I do get `<Others>` repainted as well

This is unfortunate because if I am writing numbers in `<input>` elements, when it gets repainted I lose my numbers as they reset to their original values

How could I structure my code to avoid this?

[image: in one image]

Comment: Can you provide some producible examples to play with? A sandbox can be great https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: You can try to utilize `useRef` instead of `useState` to pass messages around

Comment: Just trying to reproduce it in codesandbox and all my attempts are indeed working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed works, as far as components that you do not want to re-render are defined outside of the parent component

In this case, this codesandbox show the issue only because `<Others>` are defined inside the main component

If I move this component outside, then it doesn't rerender

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-swartz-ql8j2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

(the code, not the simplest one but while figuring out what was happening I've reproduced as much as possible my own code)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const wait = ms =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res("timed"), ms));

const useCombinedRefs = (...refs) => {
  const targetRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    refs.forEach(ref => {
      if (!ref) return;

      if (typeof ref === "function") ref(targetRef.current);
      else ref.current = targetRef.current;
    });
  }, [refs]);

  return targetRef;
};

const Com1 = ({ message, setMessage }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fun = async () => {
      if (message) {
        await wait(4000);
        setMessage("");
      }
    };

    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    fun(stillMounted);
    return () => (stillMounted.value = false);
  }, [message]);

  return <Message show={message ? 1 : 0}>{message}</Message>;
};

const Com2 = ({ setMessage }) => {
  const test = async () => {
    await wait(4000);
    setMessage("important message");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    test();
  }, []);
  return <></>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const myRef1 = useRef();
  const myRef2 = useRef();

  const Others = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const innerRef = useRef();
    const combinedRef = useCombinedRefs(ref, innerRef);

    const write = () => (combinedRef.current.value = 3);

    return <input ref={combinedRef} onClick={write} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Com1 message={message} setMessage={setMessage} />
      <Others ref={myRef1} />
      <Others ref={myRef2} />
      <Com2 setMessage={setMessage} />
    </>
  );
}

const Message = styled.div`
  background: ${props => (props.show ? "#ababab" : "#fff0")};
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
  min-height: 50px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Conponent renders or re-renders somewhere inside this component, while you did not post `<Others>` source code.

It cannot be managed from outside, IFAIK.

React really have instrument to control re-rendering like `shouldComponentUpdate`, `React.memo`, `React.PureComponent` - so you can select one (inside of `<Others>`).